# session_write_close() raises "TypeError: Session callback must have a return value of type bool, int returned" error in PHP 8.1

Tags: php, php-8.1

I'm testing **PHP 8.1.9** and when I try calling

```
session_write_close();
```

It gave me a `TypeError: Session callback must have a return value of type bool, int returned` error.

Maybe that one relates with this line in [php-src/ext/session/mod_user.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/mod_user.c#L65)

Now I don't know how to fix this on my end.

Comment: Presumably, you are using a [Custom Session Handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php), and one of its callback functions doesn't match [the documented signature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). Search your code for "session_set_save_handler" if you're not sure where to look next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @IMSop. You saved my day!

After searching in the code, we are using `session_set_save_handler()` like this

```
session_set_save_handler(
    array(&$my_custom_session, 'open'),
    array(&$my_custom_session, 'close'),
    array(&$my_custom_session, 'read'),
    array(&$my_custom_session, 'write'),
    array(&$my_custom_session, 'destroy'),
    array(&$my_custom_session, 'gc')
);
```

And in `MyCustomSession`, the `write` function returns `int|boolean` based on `file_put_contents`

```
/**
 * @param string $id
 * @param mixed $data
 * @return int|boolean
 */
public function write($id, $data)
{
    $my_custom_session_file_path = self::SESSION_PREFIX_PATH . $id;
    return file_put_contents($my_custom_session_file_path, $data);
}
```

After **forcing write() funtion to return a boolean value**, it's OK now.

```
/**
 * @param string $id
 * @param mixed $data
 * @return boolean
 */
public function write($id, $data)
{
    $my_custom_session_file_path = self::SESSION_PREFIX_PATH . $id;
    return file_put_contents($my_custom_session_file_path, $data) ? true : false;
}
```